# Read Json files over List of HTTPs location using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to read JSON files from HTTP using spark. Since it's not an HDFS or any place where Spark can read data easily and convert it to a data frame. The URL(S) is HTTPS and needs a token and a bunch of headers to successfully retrieve the response. Is there a way to achieve this task? The response is like this which can be easily converted to a row in the data frame.

```
{
    "code": "403010",
    "message": "message 1"
}
{
    "code": "403010",
    "message": "message 1"
}
{
    "code": "403010",
    "message": "message 1"
}
```

Now the response is weird because there are multiple JSON heads but it is the actual response from the API.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you add the code you've written so far ? I don't think it's spark related though. you're asking about parsing an HTTP request right ?

Comment: pretty clear question it is. He want to parse json fethed from url with spark.

Answer (score 0):

answer is provided to this url.(for others) [Get Results From URL using Scala Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52521043/get-results-from-url-using-scala-spark)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SQLContext, SparkSession}

def GetUrlContentJson(url: String): DataFrame ={
    val result = scala.io.Source.fromURL(url).mkString
    //only one line inputs are accepted. (I tested it with a complex Json and it worked)
    val jsonResponseOneLine = result.toString().stripLineEnd 
    //You need an RDD to read it with spark.read.json! This took me some time. However it seems obvious now 
    val jsonRdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(jsonResponseOneLine :: Nil) 

    val jsonDf = spark.read.json(jsonRdd)
    return jsonDf
}  
val response = GetUrlContentJson(url)
response.show
```